# Como adicionar um Library no modulo principal [ module-info.java ]?

Tags: java, jssc

Eu utilizo o pacote jssc para acessar porta serial.
eu adicionei ele ao modulo principal

```
module DeskCheck {
  requires java.desktop;
  requires java.logging;
  requires jssc;
}
```

Mas acredito estar fazendo de forma errada,  pois ocorre erro dizendo que módulo não existe.

```
Creating jlink image in dist\jimage/.
Executing: C:\Program Files\jdk-12.0.2\bin\jlink.exe --module-path dist\DeskCheck.jar;C:\Program Files\jdk-12.0.2\jmods --add-modules DeskCheck --output dist\jimage --compress=2
Error: Module jssc not found, required by DeskCheck
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está sofrendo com os *módulos automáticos*.

Módulos automáticos são módulos nomeados que são criados automaticamente para um JAR não-modular. Isso acontece quando o JAR é colocado no `module-path` (como dependência) de uma aplicação modular.

Em outras palavras: Arquivos JAR não modulares se tornam modulares quando usados por uma aplicação modular.

---

Vamos dizer que temos uma aplicação modular "`app`" que quer usar um JAR não-modular `lib.jar` (não tem `module-info`). Para rodarmos o `main` do `app` (com.app.Main.class) usaremos o seguinte comando:

```
java --module-path appClasses lib --module app/com.app.Main
```

No comando acima, `appClasses` é a pasta onde `app` tem suas classes e `lib` é a pasta onde temos o JAR `lib.jar`.

Assim `lib.jar` (que está na pasta `lib`) automaticamente se torna modular para `app`. Esse módulo tem o mesmo nome que o nome do JAR (sem a extensão `.jar`; hífens ("-") se tiver, são substituídos com pontos ("."); a versão, se tiver, é retirada também). O módulo `app` ainda tem que `requires` o módulo do JAR pelo seu nome.

---

## Que pacotes os módulos automáticos `exports`?

Ele `exports` todos os pacotes do JAR.

## Que módulos ele `requires`?

Ele `requires` todos os módulos no `module-path`.

---

## Exemplo

Esse exemplo irá criar 2 aplicações. A primeira aplicação irá representar uma biblioteca de terceiros, e a segunda vai ser uma aplicação modular que vai estar usando a primeira.

### A biblioteca não-modular

```
// matematica-iz/src/matematica/iz/CalculoBasico.java
package matematica.iz;

public class CalculoBasico {
  public static int soma(int a, int b) {
      return a + b;
  }
}
```

```
C:\exemplo-modulo-automatico\matematica-iz> tree /F /A
|   
\---src
    \--matematica
        \---iz
                CalculoBasico.java
```

#### Compilando a classe:

```
C:\exemplo-modulo-automatico\matematica-iz> javac -d out src/matematica/iz/CalculoBasico.java
```

#### Criando o JAR:

```
C:\exemplo-modulo-automatico> jar -cf matematica-iz.jar -C matematica-iz/out .
```

### A aplicação modular

```
// mat.app/src/com/exemplo/Main.java
package com.exemplo;

import matematica.iz.CalculoBasico;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int soma = CalculoBasico.soma(4, 7);
      System.out.println("O resultado da soma é: " + soma);
  }
}
```

```
// mat.app/src/module-info.java
module mat.app {
 requires matematica.iz;
}
```

Note que a aplicação acima `requires` o módulo do JAR (automático) pelo seu nome, que vai se transformar de `matematica-iz.jar` para `matematica.iz`

```
C:\exemplo-modulo-automatico\mat.app> tree /F /A
|   
\---src
    |   module-info.java
    |   
    \---com
        \---exemplo
                Main.java
```

#### Movendo `matematica-iz.jar` para a aplicação do `mat.app`:

```
C:\exemplo-modulo-automatico> mkdir mat.app\lib
C:\exemplo-modulo-automatico> move matematica-iz.jar mat.app\lib\
        1 arquivo(s) movido.
```

Agora, aqui está a estrutura do nosso diretório

```
C:\exemplo-modulo-automatico> tree /F /A
|           
+---matematica-iz
|   |   
|   +---out
|   |   \---matematica
|   |       \---iz
|   |               CalculoBasico.class
|   |               
|   \---src
|       \---matematica
|           \---iz
|                   CalculoBasico.java
|                   
\---mat.app
    |   
    +---lib
    |       matematica-iz.jar
    |             
    \---src
        |   module-info.java
        |   
        \---com
            \---exemplo
                    Main.java
```

#### Compilando a aplicação:

```
C:\exemplo-modulo-automatico\mat.app> javac --module-path lib -d out src/module-info.java src/com/exemplo/Main.java
```

#### Executando a aplicação

```
C:\exemplo-modulo-automatico\mat.app> java --module-path out lib --module mat.app/com.exemplo.Main
O resultado da soma é: 11
```

### Usando `jdeps`

```
C:\exemplo-modulo-automatico\mat.app> jdeps --module-path lib out -s --module mat.app
mat.app -> matematica.iz
mat.app -> java.base
```

---

Além desse conceito, temos também os *módulos sem-nome*, mas isso eu deixo para você pesquisar.